# PHP : Don't show duplicated MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

maybe from the title its looks like this is a duplicated question, but I've checked all other question and no one is like mine, my problem is that I've a `mysql` query on `Codeigniter` like so :

```
    function getApplication($product_id){
      $this->db->from('tapplicationproduct')
                ->where('nProduct',$product_id)
                ->join('tapplication','tapplication.nApplication=tapplicationProduct.nApplication');

              $query = $this->db->get();
              $ret['rows'] = $query->result();
              $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

              return $ret;
    }
```

and here's the the view :

```
<div class="col-md-3">              
    <select name="manufact" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Selectioner Constructeur</option>
    <?php
      foreach ($app as $row) {
      $ManName = $Product_model->getManName($row->nManufacturer);
      echo "<option value='".$row->nSerie."'>".$ManName."</option>";
      }
    ?>  
    </select>
</div>
```

The problem is that for some products I got duplicated entries :

[image: Problem Demonstration]

I've tried the mysql instruction `GROUP BY` to group the results but the problem is that I need all the `$row->nSerie` to filter the next section of the results.

What I mean is that when a user clicks on the `Constructor` a second `Select` **tag** will appear with the `Series` of the relevant `Constructor`

I've done this but I can't figure out how to remove the duplicated entries and keep the ability to access their `$row->nSerie`
I hope I can find some help about this problem, and thanks to every on in advance.

Comment: You can probably use `DISTINCT` to get unique data.

Comment: ^ or you can use a GROUP BY

Comment: @SariRahal but this can't solve my problem

Comment: If you just need manufacurers why are you querying through the product model... use your manufacturer model.

Comment: So, for each instance of `'ALFA ROMEO'` that you see there, is there a unique `nSerie`?

Comment: or you could `array_unique` after getting the results, keep the original for filtering

Comment: @A.O. can you please help me with a code?

Comment: If you need the user to be able to select a particluar `nSerie` value, then you actually do need to display every one. I would suggest selecting a different column to add to the text portion of the `<option>` to disambiguate the records.

Comment: I have an idea but I can't figure out how to implement it the idea is to store them in an array but how to submit them in the `form` I can't find out how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ths solution is to use the `array_unique()` php function, since the mysql results returned by the query is an array then we can use `array_unique()` to eliminate the duplicated values like so :

```
<select name="manufact" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option value="" selected="selected">Selectioner Constructeur</option>
<?php
  $apps = array_unique($app);
  foreach ($apps as $row) {
  $ManName = $Product_model->getManName($row->nManufacturer);
  echo "<option value='".$row->nSerie."'>".$ManName."</option>";
  }
?>  
</select>
```

And then store the keys that are going to be in the second pat of the form like so :

```
foreach ($app as $row) {
    echo "<input name='napp[]' value='".$row->nApplication."' type='hidden'>";
}
```

Now when the `form` is submitted you can the `napp` **Array** in the `Where` condition of the `MySQL` query

Answer (score 1):

You can use Distinct before `get()`.

```
 function getApplication($product_id){
      $this->db->from('tapplicationproduct')
                ->where('nProduct',$product_id)
                ->join('tapplication','tapplication.nApplication=tapplicationProduct.nApplication');
              $this->db->distinct();
              $query = $this->db->get();
              $ret['rows'] = $query->result();
              $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

              return $ret;
    }
```

Comment: and how can I access the nSerie of each instance?

Comment: Nothing has been changed when adding that line

Comment: maybe because are not the same results in row, you can use `groupBy nManufacturer`

Comment: I've used it but it only display the first one, and I can't get the other `nManufacturer` of the other rows to use them in the second part of the form